# How far back do you support Android Apps?

Tags: java, android, standards

Just curious as to standard practice for writing a new app.

Do you write your code to support all the way back to API 15 (Android 4) and try to support basically all Android platforms out there?  Or is it mostly "code for the most recent and if someone complains, add back support"?

I'm using the java.time lib and am finding it's only available in Java API 26 (Android 8). Should I just use this directly?  Or include code to check the phones version and add in code for those older versions?

Thanks!

Comment: For java.time, take a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards. Generally I'd recommend writing for API 21+ right now, as it's the first that natively supports vector drawables and has a lot of view api changes to conform for material design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As far back as it's convenient to support.**

If I can support an earlier version by avoiding the use of some minor convenience added in later versions, I'll typically support the old versions without a second thought. A practical way to approach this is to set your minimum SDK version to something even lower than you think you might want to support, and gradually raise it as you encounter reasons to do so. I need a compelling reason to support older versions if doing so requires a significant amount of extra work.

**Know your target audience.**

The developer dashboard is useful, but it's not everything. I'm working on an app right now that I expect to be used on old, retired phones that people have dedicated to a specific hobby. That's an example of a compelling reason to support old Android versions. I've also worked on an app that needed to support Android 2.1 (when 6.0 was current) because the customers using it had a large investment in old hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was leaning toward these thoughts on my own as well.  The answer can be extremely reliant on the audience for the particular app for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think Android 4 already supports a lot. I'm currently working on a Launcher application and I've had 0 issues supporting everything from API version 14 and up.

When you really need a higher API version for a specific function / library, I'd recommend to pick 5 or 6, they also support a pretty large percentage of devices (see link for source).

But I think as many developers as possible should support older devices. For most purposes older Android phones are already fast enough. If more developers would support older phones (and devices), they wouldn't be dumped in drawers so fast (that's just a waste). In my experience nothing more than software is responsible for this behaviour (isn't Windows Phone a good example of what lack of software can do to a - in my opinion - very good operating system?).

Android 4.0 is my minimum though, going lower would require me much more time.

**For a good overview of the users divided by Api versions, you can visit:**
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make an app for Android 8 and newer versions, you are going to cover only about 30% of Android devices at the moment.

You can check the developer dashboard for the distribution of devices: [Developer dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards)

At first you can focus on developing the app for newer devices and write fallback code for older devices later.

It also depends on who your target users are.

Comment: Nice! That dashboard is being added to my favorites bar now. Thanks.